# How can i use ajax load database without F5 page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a template phtml file: latestnews.phtml

```
<?php $items = $this->getNewsPost();?>

                     <div class="block block-poll news-extra-block">
                         <div class="block-title">
                            <strong> <?php echo $this->__('Best News'); ?></strong>
                              </div>

   <?php
     $i = 0;
         foreach ($items as $item):
        ?>
        <ul>   
        <div class="postnews">      
           <strong><span><a href="<?php echo $item->getUrl(); ?>">>><?php echo $item->getTitle(); ?></span></strong></a>   
           </div> 

         </ul>
    <?php
        if (++$i == 5) break;
        endforeach;
    ?> 
 </div>
```

Now, i want when i add data in database latest news automatic load without F5 page. All help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax and setInterval to load latest news on some time frame

Example

```
setInterval(function(){ 
       your ajax code to load latest news

},5000);
```

This will call your ajax after every 5 sec

Comment: No it won't. You need to use `setInterval` for that.

Comment: @MilanSimek yes i have updated to setInterval