# How to use ajax to auto load Latest News?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, ajax

[image]

How can I use ajax auto load Best News?  when I add news in admin, Best News will update without F5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use ajax load database without F5 page?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86642/how-can-i-use-ajax-load-database-without-f5-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax with setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   //call your ajax here to check and load latest news and update your news block

 }, 5000);
```

This will call ajax after every 5 sec

Comment: i will send my module, can you support?

Comment: Can i know your skype or gmail?

Comment: check  my profile

Comment: [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31150/minesh-patel?tab=profile)

Comment: done, please check your email.